# When exactly was the solenoid question reopened?

Tags: support, specific-question, vote-to-close

The question [Electromagnetic lens to focus cosmic rays](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41706/12102) was rapidly closed and then reopened.

I've tried that new timeline thingy on the left (below the voting buttons) and I can see when closing started and when it completed (on `2020-02-29` at `05:05:14z` and `17:18:47z` respectively) and a time associated with the reopening (`2020-03-01` at `00:35:05z`), but I am not sure if that's when the first reopen vote happened (which would probably have been mine at `00:16:03`) or if it's when the question was actually reopened.

How long was this question closed and the posting of answers blocked by five users in this case? Did it receive a speedy reopen by moderator, or did four other users concur with my vote within 20 minutes, or are some of the indicated times incorrect, or is my interpretation of them incorrect, or something else?

**Why am I asking?**

Usually a reopen happens more slowly than a close. *My thinking on this is that* closing sometimes happens based simply on other users' views, especially reflexive "me to" voting following a comment from a high rep user, *but reopeners generally apply some careful reading and deliberation on their own.* It takes time for four more reopeners to do so.

> [image: screen shot of a time]
>
> [image: screen shot of a time]
>
> [image: screen shot of a time]

my reopen vote:

> [image: screen shot of my reopen vote]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The review started Mar 1 at 0:35:05, and completed March 2 at 13:03:57, with 3:2 vote in favour of reopening

Your vote wasn't counted in that reopen decision apart from triggering it.

[image: time review was completed]

I obtained the time the review was completed by hovering over the relevant part of the timeline, as shown in the above screen shot

Comment: @uhoh If you click on the "reopen" in the timeline, this brings you to https://space.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/21512, where you can see who reviewd when and with what action, giving you the times and 3:2 ratio.

Comment: for the times, @Polygnome, you just need to hover on the timeline -- which uhoh did (as you can see in his screengrabs) it appears he just didn't on the one time he was asking about. Of course, it's possible that asking for the time was just a pretext for asking about that question in meta

Comment: @uhoh I am sorry but the meaning of your last comment eludes me. Did I do something wrong? If so, please be so kind and be blunt about it, I'm enormously bad at reading feelings between the lines.